# Battery & CPU usage & temperature measures results meaning

Tags: android, performance, cpu-usage, temperature, batterymanager

so i saw how to take **CPU usage and temperature**, i also have the **Battery temperature** and **light sensor** result.
It's just that i get the numbers and don't know what does they say..
I understood that for CPU temperature 70C is high and 100C is critical.

**can someone please help me understand what is a low/medium/high/critical range for each of those?**

some results for example:

```
Light Status :  1645.0(lux) 
CPU info     :  Usage: 82%  Temperature= 63~C
Battery Info :  Status= 100%  Temperature= 34.5~C
```

the "light status" is sometimes at about 100-300 and sometimes 1000+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my brief look, I couldn't find exactly what you want but here's a dump of my knowledge.

Battery capacity is a function of temperature among other things. You can understand this by realizing that batteries supply current through a restorable chemical reaction. Chemical reactions are very sensitive to temperature. Battery specifications all include an operational temperature range as well as specify that the capacity was determined at a certain temperature.

"Battery Info :  Status= 100%  Temperature= 34.5~C" The charge status means what it says, though there are some caveats that I won't get into here. The temperature is just that measured, I assume, by the battery itself. To give this value any meaning, compare it against the battery's specifications. Also note that the battery temperature is a function of how long your device has been running, discharge or charging status, etc.

"low/medium/high/critical range" To get these specifications, find the manufacturer and model number on the battery, and then check out the manufacturer's website. You may be able to find the relevant information just from the manufacturer's product catalog if you can't find the actual specification.

=======

"CPU info     :  Usage: 82%  Temperature= 63~C" Usage is generally the amount of time not in an idle state. Depending upon how they want to measure usage, it can be >100% for a multi-core system. What "temperature=63C" means is much more difficult to pin down since there are a whole host of temperature measurements obtainable from the processor, the package and the motherboard. Perhaps one of the most useful specifications is the manufacturer's *packaging* specification. Manufacturers tend to hide a lot of specifics but they have to let the laptop/desktop/server designers know enough to design their products.

(What exactly CPU temperature means is a lot more complex. First off, you can measure the temperature externally in a variety of ways from directly using a solid state temperature sensor, to indirectly measuring it using voltage and current draw plus some assumptions. In addition, internally, there are a large number of potential meanings, from junction temperatures to die temperature and more. To complicate things further, measurements of energy dissipation (i.e. power) are generally more useful. For example, TDP, or Thermal Design Power, is used to design the cooling system around the processor.)

Here's an older article I found entitled, [GUIDE TO UNDERSTANDING INTEL TEMPERATURES](http://www.techreaction.net/2009/10/14/guide-to-understanding-intel-temperatures/). Again, it's old and temperature has been a very hot topic and processor differentiator for the last 10 years.

Comment: wow, thanks for the detailed response! so what i have learned from this,  is that there is no constant way to determine device status according to temperatures. i don't like to hear that, but it's probably the truth :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

see about light readings from light sensor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux

Comment: thanks. saw that one. is there anything like that for temperatures and usages?

Comment: Optimal temperatures for silicon devices is about 75C, not sure about particular phone. Here is a code I encountered for getting CPU load for each core https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/appspot/apprtc/CpuMonitor.java